# Calling multiple describes by require in loop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, mocha.js

So I have a lot of dirs with test files and run script for each directory in it. 
This looks like:

unitTests

--func1Tests

---- run.coffee

---- suiteGroup1.coffee

---- suiteGroup2.coffee

--func2Tests

---- run.coffee

---- suiteGroup1.coffee

---- suiteGroup2.coffee

Each run.coffee contains code like this:

```
describe 'func1 tests', ()->
  require './suiteGroup1.coffee'
  require './suiteGroup2.coffee'
```

And suiteGroup files are BDD mocha tests with describe, before/after and it.

So in console I run all tests by command with wild characters ( ex. mocha ./unitTests/*/run.coffee)

I want to programmatically run all tests by requiring run scripts by their paths (paths I get by glob).

```
describe 'All tests', ()->
  glob "unitTests/*/run.coffee", (err, files)->
    for path in files
      require path
```

But this doesn't work. I also tryed this.

```
describe 'All tests', ()->
  glob "unitTests/*/run.coffee", (err, files)->
    require files[0]
```

But this doesn't work too. Seems like mocha doesn't execute describes in required file because of using glob.

Of course I can just write bash script with console command, but I would prefer solve this by coffeescript.

I also would prefer avoid hardcoding all run paths like this:

```
describe 'all tests', ->
  require 'unitTests/func1Tests/run.coffee'
  require 'unitTests/func2Tests/run.coffee'
  ...
```

So, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some time I find resolution. 
My fault was in using callback. I changed glob to glob.sync and all works perfect!

```
describe 'All tests', ()->
  for path in glob.sync "unitTests/*/run.coffee"
    require path
```

Seems like mocha doesn't work well under async code.